# How to mock webclient in Kotlin and spring boot for unit tests with mockk framework?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, kotlin, spring-webflux, mockk

I have the following piece of code in Kotlin (using WebFlux), which I wanna test:

```
   fun checkUser(user: People.User?): Mono<Unit> =
            if (user==null) {
                Mono.empty()
            } else {
                webClient.get().uri {
                    uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                    //... building a URI

                }.retrieve().bodyToMono(UserValidationResponse::class.java)
                        .doOnError {
                            //log something
                       }.map {
                            if (!item.isUserValid()) {
                                throw InvalidUserException()
                            }
                        }
            }
```

My unit test so far looks like this:

```
@Test
fun `Returns error when user is invalid`() {
    val user = People.User("name", "lastname", "street", "zip code")
    //when
    StepVerifier.create(checkUser(user))
            //then
            .expectError(InvalidUserException::class.java)
            .verify()
}
```

However when I run it, it throw the following error:

```
io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: WebClient(#1).get()

    at io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.defaultAnswer(MockKStub.kt:90)
    at io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.answer(MockKStub.kt:42)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.AnsweringState.call(AnsweringState.kt:16)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.call(CommonCallRecorder.kt:53)
    at io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.handleInvocation(MockKStub.kt:263)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactoryHelper$mockHandler$1.invocation(JvmMockFactoryHelper.kt:25)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.Interceptor.call(Interceptor.kt:20)
```

I guess the error occurs because I havent mocked  `WebClient(#1).get()` but I am not sure how to mock it. So far I have tried:

```
every { webClient.get() } returns WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec
```

but it doesnt compile. The error says:

```
Classifier 'RequestHeadersUriSpec' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here
```

Someone knows how I can mock  `WebClient(#1).get()`? Thanks in advance

Comment: You should consider NOT mocking WebClient at all and setup a mock http server instead with Wiremock for example.

Answer (score 4):

Basically you need something like this:

- mock `ResponseSpec` - mock the body or error in whichever way you need for the respective test case
- mock `RequestHeadersUriSpec` - let the `retrieve()` method return the `ResponseSpec` mock
- mock `WebClient` - let the `get()` method return the `RequestHeadersUriSpec` mock

Here is a full example:

```
val response = mockk<WebClient.ResponseSpec>()
val spec = mockk<WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec<*>>()
val client = mockk<WebClient>()

every { response.bodyToMono(String::class.java) } returns Mono.just("Hello StackOverflow")
every { spec.retrieve() } returns response
every { client.get() } returns spec

println(client.get().retrieve().bodyToMono(String::class.java).block())
```

This will correctly print the `Hello StackOverflow` string.

Comment: Hey thanks! when I mock `RequestHeaderUriSpec` like this:
        `val mockRequestHeaderUriSpec: WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec = mockk()` I get this error: `One type argument expected for interface RequestHeadersUriSpec<S : WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<S!>`
Do you know why?

Comment: You need to specify the type argument during mocking, I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am gettting this error tho:
 ` io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: RequestBodyUriSpec(#3).uri`

Answer (score 1):

Though it may be a "historical" question, I actually also had this problem recently.

Just as what Krause mentioned, the full call path of `WebClient` should be mocked. This means the method stream in `every{}` block should as the same as `WebClient` call. In your case, it may be something like

```kotlin
every{webClient.get().uri {???}.retrieve().bodyToMono(???)} returns Mono.just(...)
```

The next question is something about the error message `io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: RequestBodyUriSpec(#3).uri(......)`.  The key to the question is **methods with parameters and without parameters are totally different things**.

Thus, for target method, a `uri(Function<UriBuilder, URI> uriFunction)` is called(a lambda expression is used here to instead of `Function` interface). However, for mock method, a `uri()` method without any parameter is called. This is why the error message said , "no answer found for ...". Therefore, in order to match the mocked method, the code should be:

```kotlin
every{webClient.get().uri(any<java.util.function.Function<UriBuilder, URI>>()).retrieve().bodyToMono(???)} returns Mono.just(...)
```

Or, the `any()` method can be changed to the real `URI` which should be as the same as the target method.

Similarly, `bodyToMono()` should also be mocked with the correct parameter, which may be `bodyToMono(any<ParameterizedTypeReference<*>>())`.

Finally, the mock code may look like:

```kotlin
every{client.get()
    .uri(any<java.util.function.Function<UriBuilder, URI>>())
    .retrieve().bodyToMono(any<ParameterizedTypeReference<*>>())}
    return Mono.just(...)
```